# Sun WTK Preverify failing in J2ME- java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: ant, java-me, midp, java-wireless-toolkit

I have written ANT script to preverify the classes.,

```
 <property name="wtkHome" location="C:/WTK2.5.2"> </property>
 <property name="midp_lib" value="${wtkHome}/lib/midpapi21.jar"></property>
   .... 
  ........
<property name="build" value="build"/>
.....
   ......    

    <target name="preverify">
            <mkdir dir="${build}/preverified"/>
                <exec executable="${wtkHome}/bin/preverify">
                  <arg line="-classpath ${wtkHome}/lib"/>
             (or) <arg line="-classpath ${midp_lib}"/>
                  <arg line="-d ${build}/preverified"/>
                  <arg line="${build}/classes"/>
                </exec>
        </target>
```

When the above script executes, it is not able to find the midp classes in the classpath, so it's showing the error,

```
[exec] Error preverifying class first.MCCanvas
[exec] java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas
[exec] Result: 1
```

But the required libraries are in the classpath, Please note compilation is fine for the MIDlet and Canvas classes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with backslashes "\"

```
<arg line="-classpath C:\WTK2.5.2\lib\midpapi21.jar"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have given the full jar location,then it got worked       <arg line="-classpath C:/WTK2.5.2/lib/midpapi21.jar;C:/WTK2.5.2/lib/cldcapi11.jar"/>

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use Antenna? http://antenna.sourceforge.net/

Your build script would use:

```
    <wtkpreverify cldc="CLDC-1.0" srcdir="${build}/classes" destdir="${build}/preverified" classpath="${wtk.home}/lib/cldcapi11.jar;${wtk.home}/lib/midpapi20.jar" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'm trying to write own build script. And the problem got resolved by specifying the whole jar location